# Geometric interpretation of addition and subtraction of Rational numbers

Tags: geometry, vectors, fractions

I am aware of the geometric interpretations of dot and cross products of 2D vectors.

Considering a rational numbers $v1=(x,y)$ and $v2=(u,v$) as 2D vectors;

> Are there any known geometric interpretations of the sum of two rational numbers and their difference?

The sum $v1+v2=(x*v+u*y, v*y)$.

P.S. I am only interested in 2D interpretation.

Comment: My geometric interpretation is 1 dimensional, rather than 2 dimensional.  Start with the real number line divided into unit segments.  To consider the rational number $~\dfrac{a}{b} ~: ~b \in \Bbb{Z^+}, ~$ divide each unit segment into $~b~$ equal sub-segments.  Now, consider $~\dfrac{c}{d} ~: ~d \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ which *alternatively causes* each unit segment of the real number line to be divided into $~d~$ equal sub-segments.  ...see next comment

Comment: Then, to perform an *integer like* binary operation on $~\displaystyle \left(~\frac{a}{b} ~\right) ~$ and $~\displaystyle \left(~\frac{c}{d} ~\right), ~$ you first have to divide each unit segment of the real number line into $~(b \times d)~$ equal sub-segments.

Comment: @user2661923 I believe the question is about interpreting rational numbers as vectors in the plane.

Comment: I guess we have to start by assuming that $v_1$, $v_2$ and their sum have been expressed in irreducible form. Otherwise, we can identify a fraction with a direction in the plane, not just one vector. For ex. $2/3$ is the direction of the line with slope $2/3$. I have seen this in the analysis of continued fractions. There is a very nice interpretation of continued fraction approximations of a given real number in those terms.

Comment: @GReyes I somewhat disagree.  The underlying  question is : "Are there any known geometric interpretations of the sum of two rational numbers and their difference?".  The OP (i.e. original poster) chose to look for a 2-dimensional interpretation, in order to answer the underlying question.  This does not imply that his underlying question can't be answered in 1-dimension.

Comment: I am interested in the 2D case.